# Facebook Friend Invite External Website

Tags: facebook

I have been attempting to build a web site that is connected to Facebook. I have really been struggling with Facebook's API documentation and the examples on the web (including SO).  It seems the API is constantly changing so most information available is no longer valid.  Using a mixture of the [Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) and the [Facebook Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) I have been able to allow a user to log into Facebook, grant my web site offline_access (this is for the WPF client aspect of the system) permissions and pull basic friend information.  I have hit a wall with creating a friend invitation control. I followed the Facebook documentation and produced what's bellow.  I removed the unnecessary code to keep the post short.

```
   <div id="fb-root">
     <fb:serverFbml style="width: 755px;">
        <script type="text/fbml">
           <fb:fbml>
              <fb:request-form  method="POST" invite="true" type="My App Name"
                content="You have been invited to xxxx. <%= Server.HtmlEncode(@"<fb:req-choice url=""http://apps.facebook.com/appname/"" label=""OK"" />") %>" >
                   <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false" actiontext="Invite your friends to use this application." />
                   <fb:request-form-submit />
                   </fb:request-form>
            </fb:fbml>
          </script>                    
    </div>
    <form id="MainForm" runat="server">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
     </form> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        FB.init({
            appId: 'xxxxx',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    </script>
```

I don't receive any errors but the code does not render the friend invite control.  I checked it on the [Java Script Test Console](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/) and it renders there.  There is something obvious that I'm doing wrong so I would really appreciate some help on this.  Please let me know if there is any other information needed before starting to flame me for writing a dumb question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also was in this situation, and somehow I solved it.

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"><body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
         FB.init({appId: 'APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});        

             FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                 login();
             });
             FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {

                 logout();
             });         
             FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                 if (response.session) {
                     login();
                 }
             });
         }; 
</script>
<div id='outside_invite_box' style='display: none;'></div>
<div id='inside_invite_box'><fb:serverfbml width="615">
    <script type="text/fbml">
        <fb:request-form action="friends.php"
            method="POST"
            invite="true"
            type="Invite"           
            content="Welcome to MyApp <fb:req-choice url='http://example.com' label='Join' />">
            <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false"
                bypass="cancel"
                cols=4
                rows=5
                max=14
                actiontext="Select Facebook Friends"/>
        </fb:request-form>
    </script>
</fb:serverfbml></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think it's useful.

Comment: The code you specified is rendering. I still have some issues but I at least have a starting point. The only difference I see between your code and mine is the async loading of the FB library.  Why would this fix the issue?

Comment: Sorry yar.. I am also a beginner to facebook..If I got any info i will put here..

Answer (score -1):

if you are using RoR check out the gems RestClient and FbGraph

else start using RoR :)